# MP4BOX- postfix BaseURL name in mpd file

Tags: ffmpeg, manifest, mpd

I have generated mpd files successfully. however, I would like to change the `BaseURL` under `Representation` element.

Below command MP4Box generates `Q1_Video_10000_dashinit.mp4` as BaseURL,infact I'd like to change  `Q1_Video_10000_tsxx.mp4`

`MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -rap -bs-switching merge -out testvideo.mpd \
    Q1_Video_10000.mp4`

I want to rename the postfix "_dashinit" to some userdefine string.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no, this option has no effect..